# How to save audio time?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I have AVAudioPlayer. In first session(when user pauses audio) I want to save my audio track time elapsed and time duration. And start playing the saved time in next session(like in iBooks app). What’s the best way to do this?

My code to show time in labels

```
@IBOutlet var timeElapsed: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var timeDuration: UILabel!

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
        audioPlayer.play()
        slider.maximumValue = Float(audioPlayer.duration)
        slider.value = 0.0
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
}

func updateTime() {

    let currentTime = Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
    let minutes = currentTime/60
    let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

    let durationTime = Int(audioPlayer.duration) - Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
    let minutes1 = durationTime/60
    let seconds1 = durationTime - minutes1 * 60
    timeElapsed.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
    timeDuration.text = NSString(format: "-%02d:%02d", minutes1,seconds1) as String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use NSUserDefaults to save information over multiple app launches.

When user click pause button you can save the Elapsed Time and time duration of AudioSession to NSUserDefaults as shown below :

```
func pauseClick()
{
  if audioPlayer.isPlaying
  {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(player.currentTime, forKey: "ElapsedDuration")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(player.duration, forKey: "TotalDuration")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    audioPlayer.pause();
  }
}
```

Whenever you start next session just fetch the information from userDefaults , by calling these method.

```
func setUpNewAudioPlayer()
{
        let player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
        //before setting current time, make sure you set URL for player 
        player.currentTime  = self.getElapsedDuration()
}

func getTotalDuration() -> (TimeInterval)
{
   let timeInterval = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TotalDuration")
    return timeInterval != nil ? timeInterval as! TimeInterval : 0
}

func getElapsedDuration() -> (TimeInterval)
{
    let timeInterval = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ElapsedDuration")
    return timeInterval != nil ? timeInterval as! TimeInterval : 0
}
```

this would work!!

Comment: I have issue `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to the documentation for NSUserDefaults.

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

I think it is the best way for you to save the current time into a dictionary.

Comment: This method is used in iBooks?

Comment: Don't really know. But The UserDefaults allows you to keep information inside the device memory reserved for your application. So I think that it is the best option for your case.
Take a look to this tutorial https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/saving-data-in-ios/lessons/6